# Is "down" necessary after "calm himself"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

> Pete, still fuming, tries to calm himself (down).

Is "down" necessary here?

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not necessary, but it is idiomatic.

*Calm himself* is rather formal, in normal conversation, people would say *calm himself down*.

**Edit**: on further thought, not many people would say *calm himself down*. Most people would say *Pete, still fuming, tries to calm down.* No "himself".